# What to prefer Unicast or Multicast

Tags: networking, multicast

While I understand the difference between Unicast and Multicast ... can someone please explain in simple terms why & when would we prefer Multicast over Unicast and visa versa when using J2EE Application servers like WebLogic or WebSphere.

Comment: Possible duplicate question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338475/why-use-unicast-versus-multicast-in-weblogic-clusters

Answer (score 0):

Multicast is normally stopped at a layer-3 boundary (router) unless the router, and every router in the path, is configured for multicast routing. Because of this, multicast doesn't work on the Internet.

Many companies use multicast internally, but it is an entirely different configuration for the routers. Setting up multicast is a subject far too large to be properly addressed here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the poster is referring to  unicast vs multicast for a communication mechanism between nodes in web logic clusters.  The answer by Ron is completely accurate but I believe the poster is talking about culture communication as opposed to content delivery over the Internet.

[This post discusses multicast and unicast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338475/why-use-unicast-versus-multicast-in-weblogic-clusters) in the domain of weblogic clusters.